# Ruby ignoring boolean value in IF statement

Tags: arrays, ruby, if-statement, nessus

I am parsing some Nessus scans, and am trying to split the output of plugin 21643 into 3 different arrays, highSecArray, mediumSecArray, and lowSecArray depending on their Cipher strength.  I am going line by line and have been setting flags to put the values in their proper array.  A sample of the input is;

```
Here is the list of SSL ciphers supported by the remote server :
Each group is reported per SSL Version.

SSL Version : TLSv12
  Medium Strength Ciphers (&gt; 64-bit and &lt; 112-bit key)
      EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA         Kx=DH          Au=RSA      Enc=3DES-CBC(168)        Mac=SHA1   
      ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA       Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA      Enc=3DES-CBC(168)        Mac=SHA1   
      DES-CBC3-SHA                 Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=3DES-CBC(168)        Mac=SHA1   

  High Strength Ciphers (&gt;= 112-bit key)
      DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA           Kx=DH          Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(128)         Mac=SHA1   
      DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA           Kx=DH          Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(256)         Mac=SHA1   
      ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA         Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(128)         Mac=SHA1   
      ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA         Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(256)         Mac=SHA1   
      AES128-SHA                   Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(128)         Mac=SHA1   

The fields above are :

  {OpenSSL ciphername}
  Kx={key exchange}
  Au={authentication}
  Enc={symmetric encryption method}
  Mac={message authentication code}
  {export flag}
```

I have it trimmed down to an array with just the following, which is saved in an array (one line per array element)

```
SSL Version : TLSv12
  Medium Strength Ciphers (&gt; 64-bit and &lt; 112-bit key)
      EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA         Kx=DH          Au=RSA      Enc=3DES-CBC(168)        Mac=SHA1   
      ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA       Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA      Enc=3DES-CBC(168)        Mac=SHA1   
      DES-CBC3-SHA                 Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=3DES-CBC(168)        Mac=SHA1   

  High Strength Ciphers (&gt;= 112-bit key)
      DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA           Kx=DH          Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(128)         Mac=SHA1   
      DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA           Kx=DH          Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(256)         Mac=SHA1   
      ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA         Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(128)         Mac=SHA1   
      ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA         Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(256)         Mac=SHA1   
      AES128-SHA                   Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(128)         Mac=SHA1
```

My issue is with splitting the different strengths into different arrays. I have the following code to do it, which should work but does not.  It fills all 3 arrays with each line, ignoring the if stating the flag must be set to true.  I am outputting the actual flag values with the lines are they are properly set.

```
(1..count).each do |inc|
      version = hash[inc][0].split(" : ")[1]
      highSecArray = mediumSecArray = lowSecArray = []
      highFlag = mediumFlag = lowFlag = false

      puts "=-_-=-_-=-_-=-_-=-_-=-_-=-_-=-_-=-_-=-_-=#{inc}\\/#{version}=-_-=-_-=-_-=-_-=-_-=-_-=-_-=-_-=-_-=-_-=-_-="
      puts hash[inc]

      hash[inc].each do |line|
        if line.include? "Low Strength Ciphers"
          lowFlag = true
          mediumFlag = highFlag = false
        elsif line.include? "Medium Strength Ciphers"
          mediumFlag = true
          lowFlag = highFlag = false
        elsif line.include? "High Strength Ciphers"
          highFlag = true
          lowFlag = mediumFlag = false
        else
          puts "High:\t#{highFlag}\nMedium:\t#{mediumFlag}\nLow:\t#{lowFlag}\nLine:#{line}\n\n"

          highSecArray << line if line != "" && highFlag == true
          mediumSecArray << line if line != "" && mediumFlag == true
          lowSecArray << line if line != "" && lowFlag == true
        end # end if
      end
      puts "-----------------------High-----------------------"
      puts highSecArray
      puts "-----------------------Medium-----------------------"
      puts mediumSecArray
      puts "-----------------------Low-----------------------"
      puts lowSecArray
  end # end 1..count.each do
```

The console output I have been using to debug is as follows, it has the input at the top, then the current state of the boolean operators for each line (along with the line itself), followed by each array's contents in the end.  The medium array should only have 2 lines, high should have 8 and the low should be empty, but all 3 have all the lines in them.

```
=-_-=-_-=-_-=-_-=-_-=-_-=-_-=-_-=-_-=-_-=1\/TLSv12=-_-=-_-=-_-=-_-=-_-=-_-=-_-=-_-=-_-=-_-=-_-=
SSL Version : TLSv12
  Medium Strength Ciphers (> 64-bit and < 112-bit key)
      ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA       Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA      Enc=3DES-CBC(168)        Mac=SHA1   
      DES-CBC3-SHA                 Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=3DES-CBC(168)        Mac=SHA1   

  High Strength Ciphers (>= 112-bit key)
      ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA         Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(128)         Mac=SHA1   
      ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA         Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(256)         Mac=SHA1   
      AES128-SHA                   Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(128)         Mac=SHA1   
      AES256-SHA                   Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(256)         Mac=SHA1   
      ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256      Kx=ECDHE       Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(128)         Mac=SHA256  
      ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384      Kx=ECDHE       Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(256)         Mac=SHA384  
      RSA-AES128-SHA256            Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(128)         Mac=SHA256  
      RSA-AES256-SHA256            Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(256)         Mac=SHA256  


High:   false
Medium: false
Low:    false
Line:SSL Version : TLSv12

High:   false
Medium: true
Low:    false
Line:      ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA       Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA      Enc=3DES-CBC(168)        Mac=SHA1   

High:   false
Medium: true
Low:    false
Line:      DES-CBC3-SHA                 Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=3DES-CBC(168)        Mac=SHA1   

High:   false
Medium: true
Low:    false
Line:

High:   true
Medium: false
Low:    false
Line:      ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA         Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(128)         Mac=SHA1   

High:   true
Medium: false
Low:    false
Line:      ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA         Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(256)         Mac=SHA1   

High:   true
Medium: false
Low:    false
Line:      AES128-SHA                   Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(128)         Mac=SHA1   

High:   true
Medium: false
Low:    false
Line:      AES256-SHA                   Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(256)         Mac=SHA1   

High:   true
Medium: false
Low:    false
Line:      ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256      Kx=ECDHE       Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(128)         Mac=SHA256  

High:   true
Medium: false
Low:    false
Line:      ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384      Kx=ECDHE       Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(256)         Mac=SHA384  

High:   true
Medium: false
Low:    false
Line:      RSA-AES128-SHA256            Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(128)         Mac=SHA256  

High:   true
Medium: false
Low:    false
Line:      RSA-AES256-SHA256            Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(256)         Mac=SHA256  

High:   true
Medium: false
Low:    false
Line:

High:   true
Medium: false
Low:    false
Line:

-----------------------High-----------------------
      ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA       Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA      Enc=3DES-CBC(168)        Mac=SHA1   
      DES-CBC3-SHA                 Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=3DES-CBC(168)        Mac=SHA1   
      ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA         Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(128)         Mac=SHA1   
      ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA         Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(256)         Mac=SHA1   
      AES128-SHA                   Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(128)         Mac=SHA1   
      AES256-SHA                   Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(256)         Mac=SHA1   
      ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256      Kx=ECDHE       Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(128)         Mac=SHA256  
      ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384      Kx=ECDHE       Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(256)         Mac=SHA384  
      RSA-AES128-SHA256            Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(128)         Mac=SHA256  
      RSA-AES256-SHA256            Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(256)         Mac=SHA256  
-----------------------Medium-----------------------
      ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA       Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA      Enc=3DES-CBC(168)        Mac=SHA1   
      DES-CBC3-SHA                 Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=3DES-CBC(168)        Mac=SHA1   
      ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA         Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(128)         Mac=SHA1   
      ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA         Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(256)         Mac=SHA1   
      AES128-SHA                   Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(128)         Mac=SHA1   
      AES256-SHA                   Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(256)         Mac=SHA1   
      ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256      Kx=ECDHE       Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(128)         Mac=SHA256  
      ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384      Kx=ECDHE       Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(256)         Mac=SHA384  
      RSA-AES128-SHA256            Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(128)         Mac=SHA256  
      RSA-AES256-SHA256            Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(256)         Mac=SHA256  
-----------------------Low-----------------------
      ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA       Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA      Enc=3DES-CBC(168)        Mac=SHA1   
      DES-CBC3-SHA                 Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=3DES-CBC(168)        Mac=SHA1   
      ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA         Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(128)         Mac=SHA1   
      ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA         Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(256)         Mac=SHA1   
      AES128-SHA                   Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(128)         Mac=SHA1   
      AES256-SHA                   Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(256)         Mac=SHA1   
      ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256      Kx=ECDHE       Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(128)         Mac=SHA256  
      ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384      Kx=ECDHE       Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(256)         Mac=SHA384  
      RSA-AES128-SHA256            Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(128)         Mac=SHA256  
      RSA-AES256-SHA256            Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(256)         Mac=SHA256
```

I can't figure out why all the arrays are getting every value, any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: Here's a quick tip: in your subject line, you say: "Ruby ignoring boolean value in IF statement" – Ruby is being used by tens of thousands, maybe even hundreds of thousands of programmers all over the world, running millions or even billions of conditional `if` expressions every day. If you think that nobody has ever noticed that Ruby's `if` is broken and you are the first one in almost 25 years that Ruby exists to figure that out … chances are, you are wrong, and there is rather a bug in your code than one of the most fundamental features of a widely-used programming language being broken.

Comment: My implication in the title isn't that it does not work at all, more that in this instance, it isn't working.  I will try to title my questions more carefully in the future.  Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can't figure out why all the arrays are getting every value

There are no "arrays" (plural) in your code. There is only *one* array (singular):

> ```
>  highSecArray = mediumSecArray = lowSecArray = []
> ```

You are setting all three variables to the same single array. You should set them to different arrays:

```
 highSecArray, mediumSecArray, lowSecArray = [], [], []
 # or
 highSecArray   = []
 mediumSecArray = []
 lowSecArray    = []
```

Comment: Ohhhh okay, I'm still new to ruby, and other languages that syntax would just create the 3 arrays with the same starting value.  I understand now, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

The approach you're taking here is going against the grain enough you're getting tripped up on what should be a pretty routine parsing operation. Let's break down your problems:

- There's a header row that requires special handling.
- There's section identifiers that change the classification of subsequent lines.
- There's data lines that need to be parsed and sorted into bins.

The good news is your data is sufficiently well formatted that each type of line has distinct characteristics. You can use some simple regular expressions to extract the required details and do the classification.

Putting this together:

```
# Define which ciphers to expect
CIPHERS = [ :high, :medium, :low ]

# Variable to capture the version
version = nil
# No expectation as to where to file the data yet
bucket = nil

# Create a series of buckets, one for each cipher type
ciphers = Hash[CIPHERS.map { |c| [ c, [ ] ] }]

# Read through the data line-by-line
DATA.readlines.each do |line|
  # Skip lines that are blank, that is they don't contain at least a
  # non-space character.
  next unless (line.match(/\S/))

  if (line.match(/SSL Version : (\S+)/))
    # Capture the version information
    version = $1
  elsif (line.match(/(\S+) Strength Ciphers/))
    # Pull out the first word and use that as the bucket
    bucket = $1.downcase.to_sym

    # Test that this makes sense
    unless (CIPHERS.include?(bucket))
      raise "Unknown cipher type #{$1}"
    end
  elsif (bucket)
    # Add the line to the right bucket, but trim off leading and trailing spaces
    ciphers[bucket] << line.sub(/\A\s+/, '').sub(/\s+\z/, '')
  end
end

__END__
SSL Version : TLSv12
  Medium Strength Ciphers (&gt; 64-bit and &lt; 112-bit key)
      EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA         Kx=DH          Au=RSA      Enc=3DES-CBC(168)        Mac=SHA1   
      ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA       Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA      Enc=3DES-CBC(168)        Mac=SHA1   
      DES-CBC3-SHA                 Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=3DES-CBC(168)        Mac=SHA1   

  High Strength Ciphers (&gt;= 112-bit key)
      DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA           Kx=DH          Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(128)         Mac=SHA1   
      DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA           Kx=DH          Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(256)         Mac=SHA1   
      ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA         Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(128)         Mac=SHA1   
      ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA         Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(256)         Mac=SHA1   
      AES128-SHA                   Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(128)
```

For simplicity this reads in from the `DATA` block (defined by `__END__`) but your program can use whatever input source it prefers, like `$stdin` or some file.

This gives you output like this, here formatted in YAML for readability:

```
---
:high:
- DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA           Kx=DH          Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(128)         Mac=SHA1
- DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA           Kx=DH          Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(256)         Mac=SHA1
- ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA         Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(128)         Mac=SHA1
- ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA         Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(256)         Mac=SHA1
- AES128-SHA                   Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=AES-CBC(128)
:medium:
- EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA         Kx=DH          Au=RSA      Enc=3DES-CBC(168)        Mac=SHA1
- ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA       Kx=ECDH        Au=RSA      Enc=3DES-CBC(168)        Mac=SHA1
- DES-CBC3-SHA                 Kx=RSA         Au=RSA      Enc=3DES-CBC(168)        Mac=SHA1
:low: []
```